# Random value from list and interval change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few (3-4) value  tel number. 
Refresh to the page shows one random number and intervals of 10 seconds, changed to another random number. Preferably with preloader and the effect of a change.

For example

```
<div class="tel">
<ul>
<li>0 800 900 78 45</li>
<li>0 800 400 47 12</li>
<li>0 870 111 73 43</li>
<li>0 555 500 41 00</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: And what's the question? Where are you stuck (if you are)?

Comment: How to display just a random value and change them at intervals

Comment: You should post your attempts too. This is not a coding service.

Comment: All right. simply a decision that came as a download from a file, but then you have it turned awkward, and fetches PHP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var numberOfLis = $('.tel ul li').length;
function showRandomLi(){
    var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * numberOfLis) +1;
    $('.tel ul li').hide();
    $('.tel ul li:nth-child('+randomNum+')').show();
}
showRandomLi(); 
setInterval(showRandomLi, 10000);
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HkKwJ/3/

Comment: @Jared you must add 1 to the random number as nth-child is not 0 based (i corrected my answer)

Comment: The only reason I posted a fiddle was so the OP had a live demo. If you have a fiddle that works now, that's ok. :)

Comment: Thanks Nicola! Your solution in action: http://psyanalysis-kiev.com/ (telephon in top)